Postgres, pg_upgrade и TOAST
Вопрос больше консультационного характера.
На хабре был замечен комментарий:
"Вариант с pg_upgrade потребует от администратора базы меньше времени на подготовку, однако придётся обновлять все индексы(при обновлении до 12 или 13 версии) и пересобирать toast таблицы(в случае обновления до 14) . "
Если с индексами всё +- понятно, так сказать шишки набивались. То вот про вариант с toast хотелось бы получить больше информации.
Коллеги, прошу прощения что задаю вопрос без конкретной проблемы. Просветите пожалуйста.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Конкретной проблемы в данный момент нет. Интересует теория по пересбору тостовых таблиц при обновлении постгреса до 14-ой версии. Особенности и что же может пойти не так

pg_upgrade как правило требует сопоставимое время на подготовку, в сравнении с обновлением с использованием дампов, но обеспечивает наименьшее время недоступности базы при обновлении в --link или --clone режимах. pg_upgrade не требует ничего делать с индексами или с toast. Файлы данных намеренно бинарно совместимы при обновлениях через pg_upgrade.
Администратор может запланировать что-нибудь сделать дополнительно после обновления по своему усмотрению. Например, если считает, что для этого проекта что-то из новинок этого релиза окажется полезным. Процитированный комментатор, вероятно, подразумевал btree v4 и index deduplication. Про toast единственная догадка, что комментатор подразумевал (но не упомянул или вы обрезали цитатой) своё желание сменить default toast compression с pglz на lz4. Но то во-первых не дефолтное изменение, а во-вторых нужно проверять на конкретных данных. lz4 может в реальности сжиматься хуже чем pglz и не может быть рекомендован повсеместно. Рост реальной таблички процентов на 10% без положительных эффектов дело такое, не очень интересное.
А есть ли что-то в новом релизе интересное и надо ли что-то делать после обновления дополнительно чтобы воспользоваться возможностью - то нужно читать в release notes и документации по этой новой фиче.
